# Will this approach freeze the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

I am using Heroku and Amazon S3, for storage.

I'm trying to make the download dialogue appear for the audio file, instead of the browser playing it.

In one of my controllers, I have:

```
response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=@audio.filename"
response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = @audio.encoded_file_url
render :nothing => true
```

`@audio.encoded_file_url` returns `http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/19/test.mp3`.

Which seems to work on my local machine. However, I am wondering if this approach will block an entire HTTP request handler, freezing the app until the download completes.

In Heroku, a HTTP request handler is one Dyno. And having several Dynos is expensive.

Comment: It will block for the entire download, i believe s3 supports setting the content-disposition during upload then you could link directly to the file and still get the dialog

Comment: I don't understand. What if the files are already on S3? i.e. no content-disposition settings were set during the upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can rely on nginx being used (`X-Accel-Redirect` is an nginx-ism) - the [heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) imply that it's not always used.

In addition, `X-Accel-Redirect` is, to my knowledge only for redirecting to files actually on the server, not for externally hosted files. Why not do a normal redirect to the S3 hosted file (using an authenticated URL if needed) ?

If you need to set headers like content disposition, this can be done either at time of upload or afterwards. If you use fog to do your s3 business you could do it like this (assuming `storage` is a `Fog::Storage` object)

```
storage.copy_object("your_bucket", "filename","your_bucket","filename", "x-amz-metadata-directive" => 'REPLACE', 'Content-Disposition' => '...')
```

Note that this overwrites all the metadata - if you have other fields such as Content-Type, Cache-Control etc. then make sure to set them here or they will be lost.

Comment: If I do a normal redirect to an S3 hosted file, it'll have the browser play the audio file instead of making a download dialogue popup. Or am I missing something?

Comment: When you store a file in s3 you can set the content-disposition headers

Comment: Yes. If you use an S3 copy request to copy a file to itself it will let you change options like content disposition without actually copying the file around

Comment: Well there's a copy method in there - I suggest you start there

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend against letting users download files from your application via the dynos that your using to server your pages.  Any [static assets should really be served from S3](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/large-static-assets), which you can then direct users to for file downloads.

Whilst the user is downloading, your dyno is effectively just feeding that file to them, and thus unable to do anything else.